# Pandas add column to df based on list of regex patterns

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
Sentence                                                           bin_class
"i wanna go to sleep. too late to take seroquel."                      1
"Adam and Juliana are leaving me for 43 days take me with youuuu!"     0
```

And I also have a list of regex patterns I want to use on these sentences. What I want to do is re.search every pattern in my list on every every sentence in the dataframe and create a new column in the data frame that has a 1 if there is a matching regex and a zero otherwise. I have been able to run the regex patterns against the sentences in the dataframe to create a list of matches but am not sure how to create a new column on the data frame.

```
matches = []
for x in df['sentence']:
    for i in regex:
        match = re.search(i,x)
        if match:
            matches.append((x,i))
```

Comment: Can you show then the code for the part that already worked? (running the regex on the sentences)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can probably use the [`str.count`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.count.html#pandas.Series.str.count) [string method](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html#testing-for-strings-that-match-or-contain-a-pattern). A small example:

```
In [25]: df
Out[25]:
                                            Sentence  bin_class
0    i wanna go to sleep. too late to take seroquel.          1
1  Adam and Juliana are leaving me for 43 days ta...          0

In [26]: df['Sentence'].str.count(pat='to')
Out[26]:
0    3
1    0
Name: Sentence, dtype: int64
```

This method also accepts a regex pattern. If you just want the occurence and not the count, [`contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) is probably enough:

```
In [27]: df['Sentence'].str.contains(pat='to')
Out[27]:
0     True
1    False
Name: Sentence, dtype: bool
```

So with this you can loop through your regex patterns and then each time add a column with the above.

See the documentation on this for more examples: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html#testing-for-strings-that-match-or-contain-a-pattern

Comment: This is great, the str.contains  method seems to be exactly what I was looking for, thank you.